# Autoresizing different between ios 4.x and 5.0

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Been trying to figure out why this happens for a few days.

My app is supposed to have a shared view between all screens that handles navigation. So I made a nib for the navigation with a few buttons on it and added that view to the window (which I'm told is a bad choice)

This global view stores 4 navigation controllers so that users can swap between them without losing their place (much like how a tab bar works).  But it looks as if adding the view to the window has affected the way my app resizes for the in-call status bar.  In 5.0 the entire app works perfectly, but in 4.0 it's completely wrong.

On 4.0 if I enable the in-call bar on a screen it will not move at all.

If I push a view controller with the in-call bar the navigation bar appears at the top, but the view appears 20 pixels lower than it should

And if I have the in-call bar enabled, push a screen, then go back, the navigation bar moves down 20 pixels (as it should), but the view stays where it is and is clipped by the navigation bar.

What is happening on iOS 5 that isn't happening on iOS 4.x that makes these changes?  the app is all buggy on 4.3.

Answer (score 1):

Create a "dummy" view controller (UINavigationController works well). Then add your view to that. Without using a view controller hierarchy events will not be propagated correctly.

I suspect this works on iOS 5 because of the new "container" view controller system. They have moved the system to be more lenient in these areas. I can't give a more specific answer than that without seeing your entire app navigation design.

EDIT: 
Also try using the wantsFullScreenLayout property. It may help.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out later today and let you know if it works out!  I need to look into that container system.